# How can I obtain the address of internal System.pas functions?

Tags: delphi, assembly, basm

I'm working on a JIT compiler, and trying to figure out how to output proper cleanup blocks for managed types such as strings.

The disassembly of the cleanup block for a function that has one local variable of type `string` looks like this:

```
0044333C 648910           mov fs:[eax],edx
0044333F 6854334400       push $00443354
00443344 8D45FC           lea eax,[ebp-$04]
00443347 E81834FCFF       call @UStrClr
0044334C C3               ret 
0044334D E9062BFCFF       jmp @HandleFinally
00443352 EBF0             jmp $00443344
```

Unfortunately, I don't have any good way to obtain the addresses of `@UStrClr` and `@HandleFinally` so my JITter can insert them.  They're declared in System.Pas as `_UStrClr` and `_HandleFinally`, in the **interface** section, but apparently there's some "magic" going on because trying to use those identifiers results in a compiler error.

So I tried an ASM routine, where I declared a global pointer and said `mov func_ustr_clear, @UStrClear`.  This time I don't get an undeclared identifier error; I get something even stranger:

```
[DCC Error]: E2107 Operand size mismatch
```

So does anyone have any idea how to do this right?

Comment: Maybe calling Finalize is an option?

Comment: If you have madExcept, its source code is a treasure trove for such techniques

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try these functions to get the address of `UStrClr` and `HandleFinally`:

```
function GetUStrClrAddress: Pointer;
asm
{$IFDEF CPUX64}
  mov rcx, offset System.@UStrClr;
  mov @Result, rcx;
{$ELSE}
  mov @Result, offset System.@UStrClr;
{$ENDIF}
end;

function GetHandleFinallyAddress: Pointer;
asm
{$IFDEF CPUX64}
  mov rcx, offset System.@HandleFinally;
  mov @Result, rcx;
{$ELSE}
  mov @Result, offset System.@HandleFinally;
{$ENDIF}
end;
```

---

Edit:

@ArnaudBouchez also suggests some further optimization. By directly putting the value into the function return register, the function is a little faster.

```
function GetUStrClrAddress: Pointer; 
asm 
  {$ifdef CPU64} 
    mov rax,offset System.@UStrClr 
  {$else} 
    mov eax,offset System.@UStrClr 
  {$endif} 
end;
```

Further reading of the assembler use in Delphi could be found here (and the use of the `OFFSET` keyword), [`Assembly Expressions, Expression Classes`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Assembly_Expressions#Expression_Classes).

Comment: `@Result` could be replaced by `Result` here AFAIK. Or directly the result register, but the Delphi asm will do it for you so `Result` is just fine here. +1

Comment: Alternative shorter/cleaner code: `function GetUStrClrAddress: Pointer;
asm
  {$ifdef CPU64}
  mov rax,offset System.@UStrClr
  {$else}
  mov eax,offset System.@UStrClr
  {$endif}
end;`

Comment: Aha! The `Offset` keyword was what I was missing.  Thanks!

Comment: I am wondering: would that still be sufficient for 32-bit Position Independent Code (PIC) also, or would you have to add the GOT address (usu. in EBX) -- this is obviously not an issue for Win32 (and I don't know if the OP cares for other OSes).

Comment: @PhiS, sorry I have no experience about using PIC OS'es, like OSX or linux.

Comment: @PhiS PIC code would look like this, I think: `MOV     EAX,[EBX].OFFSET System.@UStrClr `